# How can I make Qutip turn a sparse matrix into a Qobject?

Tags: python, qutip

I have some operators in matrix form and I’m turning the into Qobjects. Nevertheless, these matrices are sparse.

I was wondering if I could give Qutip a scypy sparse matrix, so that when I do things like solving the master equation, the calculations become faster